# Unable to resolve component /atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/Authenticator

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I'm trying to launch ATG on JBOSS. However, I'm getting this following exception in my log

Unable to set configured property "/atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/AuthenticationServlet.authenticator" atg.nucleus.ConfigurationException: Unable to resolve component /atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/Authenticator

I was under that impression that Authenticator is a default component. can any body guess as to why this may occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please provide your Authenticator's properties file. Do you have it overridden in your module? It should be because only then error should be occurring in your logs. If yes then please remove it and verify that the override is causing the problem.

Also please paste the full error log so we can get an idea.

Comment: Yes, the error is gone once I have removed override yesterday. Thanks for the answer though. I got this error when I tried to over ride Authenticator using CustomUserAuthenticator as suggested in the other question about disabling dynadmin login.